# macports failing to install octave in a Mac 10.9.5

Tags: gnuplot, octave, macports

I am trying to install octave using macports with the command:

```
sudo port install octave
```

Everything seems to be all right until it has to install gnuplot, where I have this error message:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for octave
--->  Dependencies to be installed: gnuplot gperf grep gsed hdf5 less pstoedit plotutils qhull qrupdate transfig netpbm
--->  Building gnuplot
Error: org.macports.build for port gnuplot returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install gnuplot
Please see the log file for port gnuplot for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gnuplot gperf grep gsed hdf5 less pstoedit plotutils qhull qrupdate transfig netpbm
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port octave failed
```

Then I go to the file `/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/main.log`

and the last bit, which seems to refer to the error, looks like this:

```
:info:build Making all in docs
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/work/gnuplot-4.6.6/docs'
:info:build ./doc2gih ./gnuplot.doc gnuplot.gih
:info:build dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
:info:build   Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
:info:build   Reason: Incompatible library version: libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib requires version 4201.0.0 or later, but libgobject-2.0.0.dylib provides version 4001.0.0
:info:build make[2]: *** [gnuplot.gih] Trace/BPT trap: 5
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build   /_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/work/gnuplot-4.6.6/docs'
:info:build make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/work/gnuplot-4.6.6'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/work/gnuplot-4.6.6'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/work/gnuplot-4.6.6" && /usr/bin/make -j8 -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port gnuplot returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 89792 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
invoked from within
"command_exec build"
(procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
invoked from within
"portbuild::build_main org.macports.build"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for gnuplot: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:build Failed to install gnuplot
:debug:build can not find channel named "debuglog"
while executing
"tcl::puts debuglog {DEBUG: Starting logging for gnuplot}"
invoked from within
"catch "tcl::puts $args""
:notice:build Please see the log file for port gnuplot for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gnuplot/gnuplot/main.log
```

I have no idea how to overcome this problem other than installing octave using the binary installer...but I would like to know what is happening to the macport installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the portfile isn't forcing an update. If memory serves, `libgobject` is part of `glib2`. try:

```
> sudo port -v selfupdate
> sudo port [-b] update glib2 [-universal]
```

and then try installing `octave` again.

It might be worth checking if other libraries / ports need updating:

```
> port list outdated
> sudo port [-b] update outdated [-universal]
> sudo port uninstall inactive
```

Comment: I finally update and upgrade everything and it worked. Thanks for the answer anyway. It was a real pain...